# Prove: $\left|f^{(n)}(a)\leq\frac{M\cdot n!}{R^n}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> let $f(z)$ be analytic in $\{z:|z-a|=R\}$ and bounded by $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ in $|z-a|=R$,
>
> Prove:
>
> $$\left|f^{(n)}(a)\right|\leq\frac{M\cdot n!}{R^n}$$

So it seems like the use of Cauchy's differentiation formula and ML inequality

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

$$\left|f^{(n)}(a)\right|\leq\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \left|\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\right|\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{|f(z)|}{|(z-a)^{n+1}|}dz\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\frac{M}{|(z-a)^{n+1}|}$$

But what should be $L$? It seems like $\frac{2\pi i}{R^n}$ but why?

Comment: No, $L$ is the length of the path, for a circle with radius $R$, that is $2\pi R$. What is a bound for the modulus of the integrand on the circle?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\leq \frac{f(z)}{R^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

The integration is around the circle centered at $a$ with radius $R$, i.e. $|z-a|=R$ and the inequality should be 
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leq \frac{n!}{2π}\int\frac{|f(z)|}{|z−a|^{n+1}}|dz|\leq \frac{n!}{2π}\int\frac{M}{R^{n+1}}|dz|=\frac{n!}{2π}\frac{M}{R^{n+1}}\times 2\pi R=\frac{M\cdot n!}{R^n}.$$